# Can anyone help me figure out why these SQL queries are taking so long?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

The following snippet of code is taken from my global.class.php file. I am currently having problems with the time it takes to to perform an SQL query when the search "type" equals 'postcode' or 'part-number'. Please see below the snippet for an explanation including processing times.

```
function findOrder($type, $query) {
    $db = new db;
    $tasks = new tasks;
    
    if($type == 'order-id') {
        return $db->query("
            SELECT details.id, details.order_id, users.title, users.first_name, users.last_name, details.date_time, details.status
            FROM orders_details AS details
            LEFT JOIN orders_users AS users
            ON users.order_id = details.order_id
            WHERE details.order_id LIKE '$query'
            ORDER BY id DESC
        ");
    } elseif($type == 'postcode') {
        return $db->query("                
            SELECT addresses.id AS id, addresses.order_id, addresses.postcode, users.title, users.first_name, users.last_name, details.date_time, details.status 
            FROM orders_users as users 
            LEFT JOIN orders_details as details 
            ON users.order_id = details.order_id
            LEFT JOIN orders_addresses as addresses 
            ON addresses.order_id = details.order_id
            WHERE REPLACE(addresses.postcode, ' ','') LIKE '$query'
            ORDER BY id DESC
        ");
    } elseif($type == 'surname') {
        return $db->query("
            SELECT users.id AS id, users.order_id, users.title, users.first_name, users.last_name, details.date_time, details.status
            FROM orders_users AS users
            LEFT JOIN orders_details AS details 
            ON users.order_id = details.order_id
            WHERE REPLACE(users.last_name, ' ','') LIKE '$query'
            ORDER BY id DESC
        ");
    } elseif($type == 'part-number') {
        $query = $tasks->getProductID($query); //Change $query to product ID
        return $db->query("
            SELECT carts.id AS id, carts.order_id, carts.product_id, users.title, users.first_name, users.last_name, details.date_time, details.status
            FROM orders_users AS users
            LEFT JOIN orders_details AS details 
            ON users.order_id = details.order_id
            LEFT JOIN orders_carts AS carts 
            ON carts.order_id = details.order_id
            WHERE carts.product_id = '$query'
            ORDER BY id DESC
        ");
    }
    
}
```

Please see below execution times:

```
type = order-id
query = 106696 //(1 result returned)
page time = 0.0074
sql time = 0.0065

type = surname
query = smith //(23 results returned)
page time = 0.0725
sql time = 0.0700

type = postcode
query = **hidden** //(1 result returned)
page time = 2.6505 
sql time = 0.0125

type = part-number
query = **hidden** //(13 results returned)
page time = 2.8564 //(I also checked the getProductID() function, and this takes 0.0123) 
sql time = 0.0470
```

Page time is the time taken to call findOrder('type', 'query');

SQL time is the time taken when I repeat the query from directly within phpMyAdmin.

The only difference I can see between the order-id and surname queries against the postcode and part-number queries is that there is an extra LEFT JOIN. This doesn't explain why the same query performed in phpMyAdmin returns so quickly. I have no idea why it's taking nearly 3 seconds to return a query that should take less than 50ms.

Can anyone else see why this is happening? If you need anything else please let me know.

### EXPLAIN QUERIES AS REQUESTED

order-id:

> id    select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref  rows   Extra
>
> 1     SIMPLE  details     ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    1975    Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
>
> 1     SIMPLE  users   ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    1992

surname:

> 1     SIMPLE  users   ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    1992    Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
>
> 1     SIMPLE  details     ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    1975

postcode:

> 1     SIMPLE  details     ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    1966    Using temporary; Using filesort
>
> 1     SIMPLE  users   ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    1983    Using where; Using join buffer
>
> 1     SIMPLE  addresses   ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    1983    Using where; Using join buffer

part-number:

> 1     SIMPLE  details     ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    1975    Using temporary; Using filesort
>
> 1     SIMPLE  users   ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    1992    Using where; Using join buffer
>
> 1     SIMPLE  carts   ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    3611    Using where; Using join buffer

### CREATE TABLE QUERIES AS REQUESTED

```
--
-- Table structure for table `orders_addresses`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `orders_addresses` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `order_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `company` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `line1` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `line2` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `line3` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `town` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `county` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `postcode` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `country` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=2004 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `orders_carts`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `orders_carts` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `order_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `part_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `qty_ord` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `qty_rcv` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `cost_net` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `cost_gross` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=3629 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `orders_details`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `orders_details` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `order_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `transaction_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `date_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `postage` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sub_total` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `cart_vat` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `total` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1985 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `orders_users`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `orders_users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `order_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `telephone` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=2005 ;
```

Comment: Show what `EXPLAIN query` outputs, also add some table definitions with indexes. Does phpMyAdmin add `LIMIT` by default? Try using `mysql` client and execute those queries. Do not measure it in phpmyadmin.

Comment: I've added the explain query outputs you asked for, I'll logon to the server and execute those queries through mysql when I get a few minutes spare.

Comment: Could you also attach `CREATE TABLE` queries for those tables?

Comment: I've added the CREATE TABLE queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one,

```
function findOrder($type, $query) {
$db = new db;
$tasks = new tasks;

if($type == 'order-id') {
    return $db->query("
        SELECT details.id, details.order_id, users.title, users.first_name, users.last_name, details.date_time, details.status
        FROM orders_details AS details
        LEFT JOIN orders_users AS users
        ON users.order_id = details.order_id
        WHERE details.order_id LIKE '$query'
        ORDER BY id DESC
    ");
} elseif($type == 'postcode') {
    return $db->query("                
        SELECT addresses.id AS id, addresses.order_id, addresses.postcode, users.title, users.first_name, users.last_name, details.date_time, details.status 
        FROM orders_users as users 
        LEFT JOIN orders_details as details 
        ON details.order_id = users.order_id
        LEFT JOIN orders_addresses as addresses 
        ON details.order_id = addresses.order_id
        WHERE REPLACE(addresses.postcode, ' ','') LIKE '$query'
        ORDER BY id DESC
    ");
} elseif($type == 'surname') {
    return $db->query("
        SELECT users.id AS id, users.order_id, users.title, users.first_name, users.last_name, details.date_time, details.status
        FROM orders_users AS users
        LEFT JOIN orders_details AS details 
        ON users.order_id = details.order_id
        WHERE REPLACE(users.last_name, ' ','') LIKE '$query'
        ORDER BY id DESC
    ");
} elseif($type == 'part-number') {
    $query = $tasks->getProductID($query); //Change $query to product ID
    return $db->query("
        SELECT carts.id AS id, carts.order_id, carts.product_id, users.title, users.first_name, users.last_name, details.date_time, details.status
        FROM orders_users AS users
        LEFT JOIN orders_details AS details 
        ON details.order_id = users.order_id
        LEFT JOIN orders_carts AS carts 
        ON details.order_id = carts.order_id
        WHERE carts.product_id = '$query'
        ORDER BY id DESC
    ");
}
```

}

Comment: Not sure what you've changed but I replaced the function in my class file with the same results, just under 3 seconds on postcode and part-number.

Comment: Yes it works, but exactly the same as it currently does. There is still the issue of execution time on postcode and part-number.

Comment: OK. let me access your PC or let me go with your project access, so that can keep write better query.

Comment: try this query for postcode

"SELECT addresses.id AS id, addresses.order_id, addresses.postcode, users.title, users.first_name, users.last_name, details.date_time, details.status
FROM orders_addresses as addresses 
LEFT JOIN orders_details as details ON addresses.order_id = details.order_id
LEFT JOIN  orders_users AS users ON users.order_id = details.order_id
WHERE replace( addresses.postcode, ' ', '' ) LIKE '20138'
ORDER BY id DESC"

Comment: That fixed it!! Can you do the same for the part-number? Also how did you do it? lol

Comment: I've fixed the part number search now also. Thank you so much for your help!